# How can I get the number of messages sent by a user in a discord server and store it in a list [Discord.py]

Tags: python, list, discord, discord.py

I'm currently using this code to check the number of messages sent by a user but this approach is very slow, it is taking 1 - 2 min to calculate for each user

```py
user = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id== j, channel.guild.members)
async for message in channel.history(limit = 100000):
    if message.author == user:
        userMessages.append(message.content)
print(len(userMessages))
```

is there any other fast approach to doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Counting messages

You can use `on_message` event to count messages.

```py
message_count = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global message_count
    if message.guild.id not in message_count:
        message_count[message.guild.id] = {}
    try:
        message_count[message.guild.id][message.author.id] += 1
    except KeyError:
        message_count[message.guild.id][message.author.id] = 1
    client.process_commands(message)
```

And then use

```py
member = something  # specify member here
try:
    count = message_count[member.guild.id][member.id]
except KeyError:
    count = 0
# now `count` is count of messages from `member`
```

To get count of messages from member.
**Note:** Message count resets on your bot restart but this solution would work very quickly.

## Database

Another way to do what you want is use any database to store message count from different members.

Comment: is storing that data in json would be a good approach?

Comment: Maybe for small bots. Json is not a database. Anyway I strongly recommend you to use a database if your bot is quite big and it has a lot of servers.